# How to make input full width but with text on right?

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  /* just so you can see it overflowing */
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="wrap"><input type="text">.pdf</span>
```

From the example above, you'll see the ".pdf" is pushed outside of the container. How can I make it fit snugly **without setting a fixed-width for the text**?

The ".pdf" text is variable and can't be hard-coded.

Comment: my answer doesn't fit you?

Comment: @dippas It does, but I'm waiting to see if someone proposes a solution that doesn't depend on Flexbox. Support still [isn't excellent](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Comment: I've tried a few things with your requirements and I'm guess you are out of luck excluding `flexbox`, but I'll wait and see :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `flexbox` for that

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex
}
input {
  flex: 1
}
body {
  /* just so you can see it overflowing */
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="wrap"><input type="text">.pdf</span>
```